# É recomendável usar uma variável global para um objeto PDO?

Tags: php, pdo, design-pattern, variáveis-globais

Abaixo vou passar um exemplo de como eu utilizo hoje a conexão PDO para acessar meus bancos de dados.
Gostaria de ver com vocês, se é uma boa pratica esta forma, ou se é recomendada uma forma mais segura e eficiente.

Por exemplo:

```
<?php
require "environment.php";

global $pdo;

$config = array();
$config['options'] = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 
UTF8");

if(ENVIRONMENT == "DEVELOPMENT"){
    $config['dbname'] = '';
    $config['host'] = '';
    $config['user'] = '';
    $config['password'] = '';
} ELSE IF(ENVIRONMENT == "PRODUCTION"){
    $config['dbname'] = '';
    $config['host'] = '';
    $config['user'] = '';
    $config['password'] = '';
}

try{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$config['dbname'].";
    host=".$config['host'], $config['user'], $config['password'], 
    $config['options']);
}catch(PDOExcepetion $e){
    echo "ERRO: ".$e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

Dai na classe eu uso assim:

```
<?php

class Categorias{
    public function getListaCategorias(){
        $array = array();
        global $pdo;

        $sql = $pdo->query("Select * from categorias");
        if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
            $array = $sql->fetchAll();
        }
        return $array;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resposta curta: Não é recomendado e deve ser evitado ao máximo!

Partindo do principio de testes unitários, se você utilizar essa variável global você jamais irá conseguir mockar seu objeto.

Para conseguir isso você deve usar injeção de dependência no construtor da sua classe.

Exemplo:

```
<?php

class Categorias{

    private $pdo;

    public function __construct($pdo) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    public function getListaCategorias(){
        $array = array();
        $sql = $this->pdo->query("Select * from categorias");
        if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
            $array = $sql->fetchAll();
        }
        return $array;
    }
}
```

Você pode ler mais sobre Mock e testes unitários nesee artigo que recomendo muito:

[Testes Unitários 101: Mocks, Stubs, Spies e todas essas palavras difíceis](https://medium.com/trainingcenter/testes-unit%C3%A1rios-mocks-stubs-spies-e-todas-essas-palavras-dif%C3%ADceis-f2765ac87cc8)

Recomendo a leitura princípios SOLID criado por Robert Martin para guiar seu design de classes e evitar tais decisões que podem acoplar suas classes:

[SOLID Principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)

Em especial leia sobre o principio do DIP: Dependency Inversion Principle:

[Dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)

Comment: Obrigado Leandro! 
Vou ler os artigos que você me indicou.

Comment: Por favor se possível e concordar com minha resposta marque ela como a correta!

Obrigado

@WelitonSernajotto